# Why are my shapes flat after I added animation

Tags: html, css, animation, 3d, shapes

I have a 3D triangle with a base color for every shape, but I want the base (aka the square) to have an animated color, but after adding the animation, the triangles all lay flat all of the sudden. When I remove the animation, the shapes readjust as they should.

For the animation I hue-rotate the linear-gradient color of the square in @keframes animate.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pyramid">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 500px;
  left: 50%;

  margin-bottom: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 3.75rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  transform-origin: 1.875rem 1.875rem;
  transform: rotateX(120deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
          animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.pyramid {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.square {
  width: 3.75rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #008aff, #00ffe7);
  -webkit-animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
          animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.triangle:nth-child(1) {
  width: 3.75rem;
  top: -33%;
  background: #f1ecfb;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotateX(-68deg);
}
.triangle:nth-child(2) {
  width: 3.75rem;
  background: #f1ecfb;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
          clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform: rotateX(68deg);
}
.triangle:nth-child(3) {
  height: 3.75rem;
  left: -33%;
  background: white;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 50%, 100% 0);
          clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 50%, 100% 0);
  transform: rotateY(68deg);
}
.triangle:nth-child(4) {
  height: 3.75rem;
  background: white;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
          clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 50%, 0 0);
  transform: rotateY(-68deg);
}
```

Comment: forget about using filter, you cannot have 3D and filter at the same time

Comment: Is there another possibility to make an animating color?

Comment: You can animate colors with RGBA and keyframes

Comment: here is a codepen that shows what i mean : https://codepen.io/Bhumika107/pen/pgbXee

Answer (score 0):

I changed it so that the animation changes the background color which resolves the issue.

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0%, 100%{
    background: #ffadad;
  }
  12.5%{
    background: #ffd6a5;
  }
  25%{
    background: #fdffb6;
  }
  37.5%{
    background: #caffbf;
  }
  50%{
    background: #9bf6ff;
  }
  62.5%{
    background: #a0c4ff;
  }
  75%{
    background: #bdb2ff;
  }
  87.5%{
    background: #ffc6ff;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100%{
    background: #ffadad;
  }
  12.5%{
    background: #ffd6a5;
  }
  25%{
    background: #fdffb6;
  }
  37.5%{
    background: #caffbf;
  }
  50%{
    background: #9bf6ff;
  }
  62.5%{
    background: #a0c4ff;
  }
  75%{
    background: #bdb2ff;
  }
  87.5%{
    background: #ffc6ff;
  }
}
```